# in Loki after install get error connecting to Tor at tacp: 127.0.0.1:9050

Tags: appcenter, internet, tor

Cant get to Tor! Installed from AppCenter no problem, the Tor launcher settings show as installed in applications but I get the same error in both get error connecting to Tor at tacp: 127.0.0.1:9050 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved! 
Thank you guys. I was able to download Tor using using terminal  Info at: https://askubuntu.com/questions In this thread: 
tor browser install ubuntu 14.04
Install from Terminal:

Note: If you installed older version of Tor-Browser, in first you must clear the old .tor-browser-en folder from home folder. Just clear that by using: cd ~ && rm -r .tor-browser-en

Then type following line one by one in Terminal ( Ctrl+Alt+T ) to install Tor-Browser.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install tor-browser
Now open dash and type "Tor", click on and use.

shareedit
answered Aug 23 '14 at 16:12

KasiyA
13.7k1456109

Of course this is great for me because I am a noob, but for you guys  .. well have patience with us beginners. Thanks once more